# How to maintain persistant data from event loop in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, dom-events

I am trying to store string characters received from on data event to `k`, but it seems like `k` is only persistent in the `.on` function and not outside the function:

```
var http = require('http');

var url = process.argv[2];


http.get(url, function(res){
    k = [];
    res.on('data', function(data){

        //console.log(data.toString());
        k.push(data.toString());
        console.log(k);   // k stores a list string when .on is called
    });
    console.log(k);  // k is empty

});
```

I have trouble understanding this behavior and how to fix it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a var statement you're leaking onto global.k, but variable scope isn't your issue.  Your issue is time.  Your `console.log(k); // k is empty` is being run before any data comes in so of course it's empty.  You just need to wait until you have all the data and the res fires an end event.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = process.argv[2];

http.get(url, function(res){
    var k = [];
    res.on('data', function(data){
        k.push(data.toString());
        console.log(k);   // k stores a list string when .on is called
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      console.log(k);  // k is full :)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is one of timing, not scoping.  Your final `console.log` statement runs right after hooking up the event listener, which is before the listener function ever runs.  You need to do any work on the full array `k` in a listener to the `end` event:

```
res.on('end', function(){
    console.log(k);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try putting **var** when decalaring k:

   ```
   http.get(url, function(res){
     var k = []; // intialize k  with var.
     res.on('data', function(data){
        //console.log(data.toString());
        k.push(data.toString());
        console.log(k);   // k stores a list string when .on is called
     });
   console.log(k);  // k is empty
   });
   ```
2. Try declaring k as global variable.

   ```
   var http = require('http');
   var url = process.argv[2];
   var k = []; // initialize k here.

   http.get(url, function(res){
     res.on('data', function(data){
      //console.log(data.toString());
      k.push(data.toString());
      console.log(k);   // k stores a list string when .on is called
      });
     console.log(k);  // k is empty
   });
   ```